# MongoDb Node js .then .fail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

how can i write code that does the same thing but using .then and .fail

In the below code db.get() in line 1 returns the connection as "db" in db.collection('......).find({}) . In other words db.get() is the same thing as db; I have the connection to mongodb in a separate module.

```
db.get().collection('type').findOne({"_id":objId}, function(err, typeInfoResult){
    try{
        if(err){
            res.send(errMsg);
        } 
        else{
            var business_id = typeInfoResult.business_id;
            db.get().collection('business_info').findOne({"_id":ObjectID(business_id)}, function(err, businessInfoQuery){
                if(err){
                    res.send(errMsg);
                }
                else{
                    var completetypeDetail = {typeDetails:typeInfoResult, BusinessDetails:businessInfoQuery};
                    res.send(completetypeDetail);
                }
            })
        }
    }catch(err){
        res.send(errMsg); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below snippet out:

```
db.collection('type').find({"_id":objId}).toArray(function(err, typeInfoResult){
try{
    if(err){
        res.send(errMsg);
    } 
    else{
        var business_id = typeInfoResult.business_id;
        db.get().collection('business_info').findOne({"_id":ObjectID(business_id)}, function(err, businessInfoQuery){
            if(err){
                res.send(errMsg);
            }
            else{
                var completetypeDetail = {typeDetails:typeInfoResult, BusinessDetails:businessInfoQuery};
                res.send(completetypeDetail);
            }
        })
    }
}catch(err){
    res.send(errMsg); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example because I just hooked up MongoDB the other day:

> ./config/mongodb.js

```
 // Load MongoDB Driver
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

 /**
  *
  * Instantiate MongoDB Connection
  *
  * Additional options:
  * https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-options
  */

 // Connect database
 export const MongoDB = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // MongoDB Connection Info
   let url = `mongodb://${Singleton.currentConfig.databases.mongodb.user}:`;
   url += `${Singleton.currentConfig.databases.mongodb.password}@`;
   url += `${Singleton.currentConfig.databases.mongodb.host}:`;
   url += `${Singleton.currentConfig.databases.mongodb.port}/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&`;
   url += `authSource=${Singleton.currentConfig.databases.mongodb.db}`;

   // Use Connect Method to connect to the Server
   MongoClient.connect(url)

     .then((db) => {
       console.log('Casually connected correctly to server.');
       resolve(db);
     })

     .catch((error) => {
       console.log(`MongoDB Connection Error: ${error}`);
       reject(error);
       process.exit(0);
     });
 });
```

> ./app.js

```
 const MongoDB = require('./config/mongodb');
 // or
 // import MongoDB from './config/mongodb';

 // Acquire an object
 userDetails = { email: 'async@await.com', firstName: 'Uwot', lastName: 'Mate' };

 // Create a user
 MongoDB.collection('users').insertOne(userDetails)

   .then((done) => {
     console.log(`Added: ${done}`);
   })

   .catch((error) => {
     throw new Error(`Fecal's on fire, yo: ${error}`);
   });
```

Comment: Basically, where you have `.findOne({stuff}, function() { ... })`, get rid of everything after the first comma and replace it with a `)`, and then start chaining `.then(function() { ... })` onto it.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, you can replace all my `(something) => {` with `function(something) {`. Check out fat arrow functions.

Comment: I tried doing this but I get error saying db.get().collection("type").findOne() is not a function.

Comment: It's because of how you are instantiating `db`. It needs to be a resolved promise to chain off of it.